# Source code for Azure Cognitiveservices Computer Vision Java SDK

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, vision-api

I'm using the following java SDK library in my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-computervision</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

But I found a bug and I wanted to contribute a patch, is there any repository with source code ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I found the link to Github repository:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java